# log4j2 double dollar $$ sign meaning in configuration

Tags: java, log4j2

I am reading the configuration part of Log4j2.
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

```xml
<Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
    </Console>
    <List name="List">
      <ThresholdFilter level="debug"/>
    </List>
    <Routing name="Routing">
      <Routes pattern="$${sd:type}">
        <Route>
          <RollingFile name="Rolling-${sd:type}" fileName="${filename}"
                       filePattern="target/rolling1/test1-${sd:type}.%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
              <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500" />
          </RollingFile>
        </Route>
        <Route ref="STDOUT" key="Audit"/>
        <Route ref="List" key="Service"/>
      </Routes>
    </Routing>
  </Appenders>
```

What is the meaning of double $$ sign? e.g. $${sd:type}?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that `$` is used as an escape character. As stated in [Log4J documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution), Log4j configuration file parser uses [Apache Commons Lang's `StrSubstitutor`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/StrSubstitutor.html), and this documentation for `StrSubstitutor` says:

> The other possibility is to use the escape character, by default '$'.
>   If this character is placed before a variable reference, this
>   reference is ignored and won't be replaced. For example:
>
> `The variable $${${name}} must be used.`

I guess they want to set the value to `"${sd:type}"` so that this variable can be evaluated later at run-time. There is a good example/explanation here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#ContextMapLookup

Comment: Yes, you are correct. According to Lookup menu, http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html, it mentions that "During initial configuration processing the first '$' will be removed"

Answer (score 0):

You can set Configuration element's attribute status="DEBUG" like this:

```
<Configuration status="DEBUG">  
<properties>
        <property name="LOG_HOME">logs</property>
</properties>
```

Then record log follow the two step:

#### step 1:

Set filePattern="${LOG_HOME}/**$**{date:yyyy-MM}/all-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz"

log recored:
...
filePattern="logs/**2021-06**/all-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz"
...

#### step 2:

Set filePattern="${LOG_HOME}/**$$**{date:yyyy-MM}/all-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz"

log recored:
...
filePattern="logs/**${date:yyyy-MM}**/all-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz"
...

##### Summary:

Now you know their difference.Double $ means the result will be computed dynamically according the latter context.It's a placeholder for dynamically compute.