# Log4j difference between dollar and percent patterns in layout

Tags: log4j, log4j2, rollingfileappender, pattern-layout

Answering this [this question about log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71832298/the-presence-of-character-in-filepattern-causes-illegal-char-error-in-rollingf) left me more confused than enlightened.

There seem to be several ways of specifying the current date (with custom format) in log4j2 configuration files:

- `%d{HH-mm-ss}` ([Layouts](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html))
- `${date:HH-mm-ss}` ([Appenders](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html))

(Interestingly, the log4j2 docs consistently use `$${date:...}` in their examples, but doubling the dollar character [should escape it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39401921/112968) and make it a literal dollar character followed by a curly brace and the word "date", a colon, the format, and the closing brace.)

What's the difference between one form or the other, if there is a difference? When should one used over the other?

Is there a difference when used together in a single value? The examples contain the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="baseDir">logs</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <!-- HERE: -->
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${baseDir}/app.log"
          filePattern="${baseDir}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" />
      <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 0 * * ?"/>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        <Delete basePath="${baseDir}" maxDepth="2">
          <IfFileName glob="*/app-*.log.gz" />
          <IfLastModified age="P60D" />
        </Delete>
      </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

1. Why the double dollar in front of `$${date:yyyy-MM}`, but only a single dollar with `${baseDir}`?
2. Why `${date:yyyy-MM}` and `%d{MM-dd-yyyy}` and not `%d{yyyy-MM}` or `${date:MM-dd-yyyy}`?

Who can clear the confusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern placeholders like `%d{...}` can be used in:

- the `pattern` property of a pattern layout (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout)) and by extension in the `pattern` resolver of a JSON Template Layout (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html)). These patterns are replaced with a property of the `LogEvent` being logger,
- the `filePattern` property of a rolling file appender (just `%i` and `%d`). These patterns are replaced with the index and date pattern of the archived log file being created.

Lookup placeholders `${type:key}` on the other hand can be used everywhere in your configuration file and are replaced **eagerly** when the file is read (cf. [lookups](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html)). Therefore the `fileName` property of your rolling file appender will have `logs/app.log` as value.

There is however a second application for lookups: some properties, including all those that accept `%` patterns, accept `${...}` lookups that will be evaluated at a later time. In order to prevent the evaluation of those lookups at configuration time, you need to escape `$` as `$$`.

That is why the `${baseDir}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz` string in your configuration file is:

1. evaluated as `logs/${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz` at configuration time,
2. further evaluated as `logs/2022-04/app-2022-04-16.log.gz` if a rollover occurs today.

If you were to use `${date:yyyy-MM}` instead of `$${date:yyyy-MM}` all log files would be (until reconfiguration occurs) in the `logs/2022-04` folder.

The difference between `$${date:yyyy-MM-dd}` and `%d{yyyy-MM-dd}` is specific to the rolling file appender: the appender needs to know how often should a rollover occur. It does so by analyzing the `%d{...}` pattern. That is why in your configuration rollover occurs daily (`%d{yyyy-MM-dd}`) and not monthly (`$${date:yyyy-MM}`).

Another difference between those two is in the date they use: `$${date:...}` uses the current date, while `%d{...}` uses the date of the previous rollover. These might be off by one rolling period.